# Does Reverse Geocoder Google maps API for Android always return postal code?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, reverse-geocoding

I am trying to understand if Google maps Reverse geocoder API will always give me the postal code? If not of the exact latLng but at least the nearest one? 
The following JavaScript API works just good & returns Postal Code for all the valid LatLng combinations.

Could someone tell me if it will always return postal code for latLng in Android?

```
 <script>
      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 8,
          center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
          geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
        });
      }

      function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
        var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
        var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
        var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
        geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map
              });
              console.log(results[1].address_components);// Accessing Postal code
              infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
              window.alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
```